# JPA Criteria API Using Wrong Entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities, `Parent Tracking` and `Step Tracking`.

```
@Entity(name = "ParentTracking")
@Table(name = "PARENT_TRACKING", schema = "ORCHESTRATION")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class ParentTracking {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private long id;

.....

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "parentTracking", targetEntity = StepTracking.class)
    private List<StepTracking> stepTrackingList = new ArrayList<>();



@Entity(name = "StepTracking")
@Table(name = "STEP_TRACKING", schema = "ORCHESTRATION")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class StepTracking {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private long id;

    @JsonProperty("parentTrackingId")
    @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, targetEntity = ParentTracking.class, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_TRACKING_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private ParentTracking parentTracking;
```

When I use the JPA Critera API to search on the Step Tracking object to obtain a list of Step Tracking entries:

```
return repository.findAll(new Specification<StepTracking>() {

            @Override
            public Predicate toPredicate(Root<StepTracking> stepTrackingRoot, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {

                List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

                //Orchestration Step / Step Tracking Change Range.
                if (trackingSearchCriteria.getOrchestrationStepChangedRange() != null) {
                    predicates.add(cb.between(stepTrackingRoot.get(StepTracking_.CHANGED_TIMESTAMP), trackingSearchCriteria.getOrchestrationStepChangedRange().getStart(), trackingSearchCriteria.getOrchestrationStepChangedRange().getEnd()));
                }

                //Orchestration Step Tracking Status.
                if (trackingSearchCriteria.getOrchestrationStepTrackingStatus() != null && trackingSearchCriteria.getOrchestrationStepTrackingStatus().size() > 0) {
                    predicates.add(stepTrackingRoot.get(StepTracking_.TRACKING_STATUS).in(trackingSearchCriteria.getOrchestrationStepTrackingStatus()));
                }

                //Ordering.
                List<Order> orderList = new ArrayList<>();
                orderList.add(cb.desc(stepTrackingRoot.get(StepTracking_.CHANGED_TIMESTAMP)));
                query.orderBy(orderList);

                return cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
            }
        }, pageRequest).getContent();
```

The search ends up searching on the Parent Tracking entity, not the Step Tracking entity:

```
select parentt0_.id as id1_4_, parentt0_.changed_timestamp as changed_2_4_, parentt0_.created_timestamp as created_3_4_, parentt0_ where (parentt0_.changed_timestamp between ? and ?) and (parentt0_.status in (?)) order by parentt0_.changed_timestamp desc limit ?
```

Can someone help me understand why JPA is using the wrong entity to build the query?

Comment: Please also post your repository. The select statement doesn't seem to be complete since it is missing a FROM clause.

Comment: Hi @JensSchauder, I don't have a public repo of this unfortunately. The from statement seems to be generated by the specification's generic type being the entity in question. I can add ```query.select(stepTrackingRoot.get(StepTracking_.ID)).distinct(true); ```
but the outcome is still the same